# How to call java-script function with parameters where comes from a string variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

My `javascript` has more than 12 functions and all function call the following function.

`address_bar(gender, age_min, age_max, religion, country, address, zip-code, telephone);`

My question is it is possible to call this function as follows.

```
var string =  'gender, age_min, age_max, religion, country, address, zip-code, telephone';
```

Call each function as

`address_bar(string); //not working`

I get undefined variable errors for parameters.

Comment: Why don't you create a object and pass that object to function?

Comment: You could use `eval` but understand the risks involved before using it...

Comment: No because you are passing in one parameter that is a string. You can do some magic with split and apply, but if any of the fields have a comma in it, you are in trouble. You would be better off with an array or object.

Comment: @brso05, `eval` is evil https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/how-evil-is-eval/

Comment: @Satpal did you read my comment? **"but understand the risks involved before using it"** there is nothing wrong with using it in certain situations...

Comment: you can modify the code inside the function to `split` first parameter. If the resulting array has more than 1 element, you know that a comma separated string has been passed. If length is 1, you should process it as you are doing currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate way could be to put them in an array like

```
var args =  [gender, age_min, age_max, religion, country, address, zip-code, telephone];
address_bar.apply(null,args)
```

Comment: why not just call the method directly if you already have everything in variables?

Comment: address_bar(gender, age_min, age_max, religion, country, address, zip-code, telephone) is exactly the same, more readable, and less code.

Comment: @MarkEvaul But OP is saying that he is calling this method again and again and wants to do some refactoring.

Comment: no, he's saying he has 12 points that call this function.  He'd have to put this code in 12 places.  regardless, doing this, then changing the values of gender, age_min, etc would not change the values in args because javascript doesn't use pointers.  You'd have to reset args after changing any of the variables.  In that case, calling the method directly would actually be more beneficial because changing the variable then passing the variable to the method would actually work.

Comment: Not sure what is the relevance of your fiddle

Comment: the fiddle shows that if you set the array to variable (ar = [x,y]) then change x and y, ar does not change and so using apply calls with invalid values, but if you call method directly ( f(x, y) ) then change x and y, f is called with new values.  In other words, if you change your variables, you have to change your array, and if you already have variables, why not just call the method directly instead of making it more complicated like this solution?

Comment: Apparently OP wants to call different methods with same arguments which is what my answer shows how to

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string into an array by the comma, and then pass the resulting parameters into the function via `apply`, but there's a caveat: All of the parameters would be strings, so if you need to distinguish between numbers and strings, there'd be another step of looping through and parsing the result based on whatever types you're expecting. You'd also have to be careful to ensure that none of the expected values have a comma in them, or you'd be splitting a result prematurely.

Here's an example of the most basic case:

```
address_bar.apply(null, string.split(','));
```

Comment: assuming you already have the string assembled, this is the correct solution.  All the other solutions are no better than just calling the method directly with the variables you already have.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass them as one string without modifying function, you have atleast 3 options.

1) Change you function to accept one string:

```
function adress_bar(string){
    //split string and do soemthign with data;
}

adress_bar(string);
```

2) Change/split data you try to "push" into function like:

```
var gender = 'gender', age_min = "age_min", ... , telephone = "telephone";
```

and then run function with each of these variables:

```
adress_bar(gender, age_min, ... , telephone);
```

3) Make array or object of your arguments and pass them all as one.

```
var array = ["gender", "age_min", "age_max", "religion", "country", "address", "zip-code", "telephone"];

function address_bar(some_array){
//do something with some_array
}

address_bar(array);
```

Comment: Don't know why getting downvoted OP tried to pass single string as many arguments so I explained how functions and arguments works.

Answer (score -1):

This does exactly what you want:

```
var x = [ 'gender', 'age_min', 'age_max', 'religion', 'country', 'address', 'zip-code', 'telephone' ];
address_bar.apply(this, x);
```

You can read more about apply [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) :

Comment: while technically correct, if you already have all the variables, why not just call the method?